# CUDA is not working on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, cuda

I'm planning to start some CUDA development, so I'm trying to use the NVIDIA card that I have installed and I haven't yet be able to use (an NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 630M]) because Ubuntu (12.05 64 bits)seems to have many issues with it.

What I did is download the CUDA 5.5 installers and execute the following in that order:

```
NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.37.run
cuda-linux64-rel-5.5.22-16488124.run
cuda-samples-linux-5.5.22-16488124.run
```

To make the NVIDIA driver installation to work, I have to uninstall Bumblebee first. The installer wanted to override `xorg.conf` but I choose not to because some previous disastrous installations (I only get a black screen).

I used this [Blog Post instructions](http://tryknowdo.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/cuda-5-0-installation-on-ubuntu-12-04/) to validate my installation. I first executed this:

```
cptanalatriste@cptanalatriste-Inspiron-5420:/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
cat: /proc/driver/nvidia/version: No such file or directory
```

And I get that error message. After compiling and executing the CUDA samples. I'm getting this:

```
cptanalatriste@cptanalatriste-Inspiron-5420:/usr/local/cuda-5.5/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery$ sudo ./deviceQuery 
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

WARNING: Not loading blacklisted module nvidia_304
FATAL: Module nvidia not found.
cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38
-> no CUDA-capable device is detected
Result = FAIL
```

Any ideas? I suspect the Driver installation didn't go that well.